# MVC 3 pass model item to @Html.ActionLink text?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How to pass model item to @Html.ActionLink text...

```
@Html.ActionLink( @item.GetLink(),"Controller", "Action" )
```

this isn't working, if i put it in " " it becomes string. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.GetLink(), "Action", "Controller")
```

(without @ character in first parameter, and swap action and controller)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Evgeny Levin's answer, you could also download the [MvcContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/) library and strongly type your ActionLinks like so

`@Html.ActionLink<Controller>(x=>x.Action(), item.GetLink())`

I prefer this method over magic strings, and then in my solution configurations I create a new one that mimics Debug but has the value for `MvcBuildViews` set to true, and then when you compile, if you have any invalid Links to controller/action pairs, it throws a compiler error. Has saved me many times of pushing out code that doesn't pass required Action parameters

Comment: If you use strongly typed ActionLink() method - it will not work correctly with [ActionName] attribute - you lose this extensibility point. Modern version of Resharper adds support of controller and action string parameters in ActionLink() method - autocomplete and highlight of correct/incorrect pairs of controller-action.